# Delete sheets after certain sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I need to delete all sheets after a sheet called "template 1".

So far I have tried

```
Sub SheetKiller()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    j = 0
    For i = 1 To Sheets.Count
        If Sheets(i).Name = "template 1" Then
            j = i
        End If
    Next i

    If j = 0 Or j = Sheets.Count Then Exit Sub

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        For i = Sheets.Count To j + 1 Step -1
            Sheets(i).Delete
        Next i
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True 
End Sub
```

However, I get the error message "Delete method of Worksheet class failed". Anyone got a solution to this?

Comment: I have added this code into a module and tested. It works on my system without any error. I am using Excel 2013 on Windows 10.

Comment: Do you have any other workbooks open?

Comment: No, I have not. I am using windows 10 and excel 2016.

Comment: Does it delete any sheets? Have you stepped through the code to check at what point it errors?

Comment: It points to  " Sheets(i).Delete ". It might somehow think that "i" equals every sheet in the workbook, and tries to delete all of them which would return a similar error.

Comment: What is the value of `i` when it errors?

Comment: i = 12 which is the total amount of sheets in my workbook.

Comment: And what is the value of `j`?

Comment: J = 7 which is the amount of sheets to remain after I delete the sheets

Comment: Is your workbook protected? As lighthouseelk says there's nothing obviously wrong with your code.

Comment: Neither the workbook or the sheets are protected.

Comment: Do you have any "Very Hidden" sheets in your workbook (you can see them in the VBA Editor)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing that I can think of that would throw this error is having a "Very Hidden" sheet in your workbook.  "Very Hidden" sheets will not delete using your function.  Try this:

```
Sub SheetKiller()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim bFound As Boolean

    j = 0
    bFound = False

    For i = 1 To Sheets.Count
        If bFound Then Sheets(i).Visible = 0
        If Sheets(i).Name = "template 1" Then
            j = i
            bFound = True
        End If
    Next i

    If j = 0 Or j = Sheets.Count Then Exit Sub

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        For i = Sheets.Count To j + 1 Step -1
            Sheets(i).Delete
        Next i
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

This will set all sheets that are going to be deleted to be "Hidden", allowing them to be deleted without ever displaying them.  If the "Very Hidden" sheet needs to remain, then use this:

```
Sub SheetKiller()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long

    j = 0
    For i = 1 To Sheets.Count
        If Sheets(i).Name = "template 1" Then
            j = i
        End If
    Next i

    If j = 0 Or j = Sheets.Count Then Exit Sub

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        For i = Sheets.Count To j + 1 Step -1
            If Sheets(i).Visible < 2 Then Sheets(i).Delete
        Next i
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Return the `Index` number of the sheet and then delete all sheets with an index higher than that.

You need to check that "template 1" isn't the only sheet in the workbook or that it isn't the last sheet in the workbook.  You also need to delete from the last sheet backwards to the first - which I can see you've done in your original code.

```
Sub Test()

    Dim Indx As Long
    Dim x As Long

    With ThisWorkbook
        On Error Resume Next
            Indx = .Sheets("template 1").Index
        On Error GoTo 0

        If Indx <> 0 Then
            If .Sheets.Count > 1 And Indx < .Sheets.Count Then
                Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                For x = .Sheets.Count To Indx + 1 Step -1
                    .Sheets(x).Delete
                Next x
                Application.DisplayAlerts = True
            End If
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

**Edit:**  Just realised - it also needs to check that at least one sheet is visible, but guessing that "template 1" would be visible so cheating a bit and not checking for that. :)

**Edit 2:** I've added a check to make sure *template 1* exists.  Usually I'd pass this out to a separate function which would return TRUE/FALSE.

**Edit 3:** Sorry!  Changed `Worksheets` to `Sheets` so it includes Chart sheets.

Comment: When I use this  code I get an automation error in the .sheets(x).delete line. do u know why this could be happening?

Comment: @vba_user111 Not sure.  What's the exact message displayed?  Is the workbook structure protected in which case it can't delete the sheet - that'd give `Delete method of Worksheet class failed`.

Comment: "Run-time error '-2147319765':
Automation Error
Element not found. on the lline .sheets(x).delete, however the code does work and it does delete the sheets

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i).Delete
```

instead of `Sheets(i).Delete`

Comment: If you see the same error on any other computer, better to see your file closely. Because I can not see any error in the codes.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have save the file with enable macros and then try:

Replace:

```
Sheets(i).Delete
```

Replace with:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Delete
```

Comment: This returns the same error. I am sure I have enabled macros, as other macros in the same workbook works fine.