# VBA message automation error element not found

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling, automation

I have a workbook that uses a macro and makes many sheets. After one sheet, called Paste, I want to be able to delete the sheets that follow once I am done using them.

I found the following code from https://stackoverflow.com/a/53544169/11615632 and slightly modified it to use in my workbook.

```vb
Sub Deleting()
    Dim Indx As Long
    Dim x As Long

    With ThisWorkbook
        On Error Resume Next
        Indx = .Sheets("Paste").Index
        On Error GoTo 0

        If Indx <> 1 Then
            If .Sheets.Count > 2 And Indx < .Sheets.Count Then
                Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                For x = .Sheets.Count To Indx + 1 Step -1
                    .Sheets(x).Delete

                    On Error GoTo 0
                Next x
                Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            End If
        Elseif Indx = 1 Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

However, when I do this it actually *works, but* I get an error message saying

> "Run-time error '-2147319765':
>      Automation Error
>      Element not found.

The error is found on the line `.Sheets(x).Delete`

Comment: On which line is the error?

Comment: I appologize... adding it in now

Comment: @Warcupine its on the .Sheets(x).Delete

Comment: FYI it's `ElseIf`, not `Else If`.  Also, if your workbook doesn't have a sheet called "Paste", the first `If` statement will still run (`Indx` here is `0`). I assume that's correct and what you want...Finally, make sure that your `For` loop won't try and delete the single, remaining sheet.

Comment: Consider what happens when `Indx = 0`.

Comment: @BruceWayne, I have sheets titled Value, then "Paste". My original macro makes several sheets after "Paste", and I want this macro to delete all those sheets. When I run this current macro, those sheets all delete(not Value or Paste), but this error message still pops up

Comment: @GSerg what happens when that occurs? If I take the elseif part out i still ahve this issue

Comment: Why not then loop through sheets and do like `Dim ws as Worksheet / For each ws in Thisworkbook.Worksheets / If ws.Name <> "Paste" and ws.Name <> "Value" Then ws.Delete / Next ws`?  (It's a workaround, as I don't know why you get that error still...)

Comment: Well the elseif part does not handle the 0 value, does it? When 0 it will try to remove all sheets, and there must remain at least one.

Comment: @BruceWayne  this works much better. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you know that you want to keep two specific sheets ("Value" and "Paste"), instead of using the indexes, which can be a little tricky and may not always work depending on the order/added order of them, I suggest instead looking at the name of each worksheet and delete that way (as mentioned in the comments).

```
Dim ws as Worksheet
' This next line will suppress the "Confirm Deleting" messagebox
' when you go to delete a worksheet
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
For each ws in ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> "Value" and ws.Name <> "Paste" Then
        ws.Delete
    End If
Next ws
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

(This assumes the macro is stored in the workbook you want to delete the sheets from. If it's not, perhaps it's stored in Personal.xlsb, then switch `ThisWorkbook` to `ActiveWorkbook` or something more specific.)